# Shared memory: segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: c, linux, memory, shared-memory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
int main()
{
    int shmid;
    char *viraddr;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    shmid=shmget(1234,BUFSIZ,0666|IPC_CREAT);
    viraddr=(char*)shmat(shmid, 0,0);
    while(1)
    {
        puts("Enter some text:");
        fgets(buffer,BUFSIZ,stdin);
        strcat(viraddr,buffer);
        if(strncmp(buffer,"end",3)==0)
            break;
    }
    shmdt(viraddr);
    exit(0);
}
```

I am learning shared memory.I want to realize the communication between two processes. When I run this program, it always indicates this error -- `segmentation fault core dumped`. Any help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me... Fedora 20 64 bit, + valgrind...

Comment: I believe you should use `strcpy` instead of `strcat` because you don't know if there's garbage in the memory at `viraddr`. Why it works for dgunchev is probably because the memory in the address returned by `shmat` just happened to be 0s.

Comment: No, it works because `IPC_CREAT` is used to create a new segment... and, when a new shared memory segment is created, its contents are initialized to zero values. See `man 2 shmget`.

Comment: possibly viraddr is null.   can you print it after calling shmat() ?

Comment: Exactly. validate `shmget` and `shmat` *succeeded*. A little length-validation to ensure you don't overrun `viraddr` would probably go a long way too.

Answer (score 1):

Here both viraddr and buffer have the same size. For strcat() it is recommended dst size to be atleast a byte larger than the src size. viraddr should have enough space to hold buffer data just to avoid buffer overrun.

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with it. When a new shared memory segment is created, its size is equal to the value of `BUFSIZ` rounded up to a multiple of `PAGE_SIZE`. Unless the shared content exceeded `BUFSIZ` (rounded up to the nearest `PAGE_SIZE`), this doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, sometimes the memory allocation returns `FFFFF` and then throws `Segmentation Fault Core Dumped`. Reason being you don't have enough rights to access the Memory for your processes.

Simply use **`sudo`** to compile and run the code. For instance say you have these files

> shm1.c
>   shm2.c
>   shm.h

Then your commands need to be fired as following

```
sudo gcc shm1.c -o s1
sudo gcc shm2.c -o s2
sudo ./s1 &
sudo ./s2
```

If you are willing to do it on 2 different terminals, just fire `sudo ./s1` in terminal1 & `sudo ./s2` in different terminal 2